# Dim p As String = sqlcomm1.ExecuteNonQuery()- loading -1 into the string

Tags: sql, vb.net

after runnuning below code ..

```
Dim p As String = sqlcomm1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

string p is loading with `-1`, but query giving the proper output in sqlserver

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim customerID, billno, billdate, Nettotal As String
    customerID = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    billno = TextBox1.Text
    billdate = TextBox4.Text
    Nettotal = TextBox10.Text

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.22\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sales_oct_3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=a;Password=so")


    If sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        sqlcon.Close()
    End If
    sqlcon.Open()
    Dim strcommand As String
    Dim strcommd1 As String
    strcommand = "Insert into tinsales(customerID,Billno,Billdate,Nettotal) values ('" + customerID + "','" + billno + "','" + billdate + "','" + Nettotal + "')"
    strcommd1 = "select max(salesId) as salesID from [tinsales]"
    Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand(strcommand, sqlcon)
    Dim sqlcomm1 As New SqlCommand(strcommd1, sqlcon)

    Dim o As String = sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim p As String = sqlcomm1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Dim total As Double = 0
        For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim temp As Double = Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells(4).Text)
            total += temp
        Next
        TextBox10.Text = total.ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ExecuteNonQuery` to `ExecuteScalar`:

```
Dim p As String = sqlcomm1.ExecuteScalar()
```

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Also I suggest to change your inline queries to use parametrized commands, because it is safer  (protects from SQL Injection attack) and also type safe (very useful when passing `DateTime`)

```
strcommand = "Insert into tinsales(customerID, Billno, Billdate, Nettotal) values (@customerId, @billno, @billdate, @nettotal)"

Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand(strcommand, sqlcon)
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", customerID)
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billno", billno)
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billdate", billdate)
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nettotal", Nettotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate strings to build your query, you're open for sql-injection. Use sql-parameters.

To get the last inserted identity value don't use

```
select max(salesId) as salesID from [tinsales]
```

You can insert and select it in one command. Therefore use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `ExecuteScalar`:

```
Using con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.22\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sales_oct_3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sofker")
    Dim sql = "INSERT INTO tinsales(customerID,Billno,Billdate,Nettotal) VALUES(@customerID,@billno,@billdat,@Nettotal);" & _
              "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY AS INT);"
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", customerID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billno", billno)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billdate", billdate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nettotal", Nettotal)
        con.Open()
        Dim newPrimaryKey As Int32 = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Int32)
    End Using
End Using
```